# The easiest explination on how to use json in cshtml without pageload?

Tags: jquery, json, razor

I've been looking around the net now for quite some time. And yet I haven't found a good guide on how to do a call to a `.cshtml` page with `Json`, without a page call.

My question is, do you know a good and easy guide on how to do a call to a `.cshtml` page through `Json` without reloading the page.

-- Update --

When I talk about `json` I had an understanding that is was the common term for the following code

```js
function ajax_get_json()
{
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    hr.open("GET", "CallTime.cshtml", true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json", true);
    hr.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200)
        {
            var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
            var result = document.getElementById("results");

            result.innerHTML = "";
            for (var obj in data)
            {
                result.innerHTML += data[obj].item + "<br/>";
            }
        }
    }

    hr.send(null);
    result.innerHTML = "requesting...";
};
```

But im aware that this is a `ajax`call requesting a `json`format.

Comment: json stands for javascript object notation. you cannot "do a call to a .cshtml page through Json"... do you mean ajax?  Or do you somehow mean that you want to send the cshtml file in Json format? if you mean ajax, it would seem to me that you should probably go learn the basics of javascript before you start asking questions like this on stack. this is beginner stuff that you should at least be able to ask correctly.

Comment: @iAmClownShoe Yea im talking about a ajax call that gets a json format in return. I called it json in my question cause I had an understanding that it was the common word for the progress as well as the format. Im sorry, I will update my question ^^

Comment: You can't call a .cshtml page directly for JSON results, it's a View, not a Controller. Check my link out to achieve this.

Comment: ok so to clarify. an ajax call will make a call to a url that directs to a controller that lives on your server. the controller is responsible for processing the request and returning you the data that is asked for. the data returned will be in json format if you choose to format it that way (standard). this is the basic mvc concept

Comment: MVC - Models reflect your data structure ie. database tables represented as POCOS(plain old CLR objects). Controllers are responsible for processing requests and rendering views. Views are the actual html/cshtml files that the controller sends to the client to be rendered.

Comment: Would it be possible to call a `.cshtml`page like `/mypage.cshtml?ID=xxx` and get the html code back from there throug a call. Instead of using `Json`?

Answer (score 1):

This was the easiest tutorial I came across for this, using WebAPI (with an MVC project + jQuery): http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

and the main site: http://www.asp.net/web-api

Comment: Im going to take a look at this ^^ Don't know if its what im looking for yet. But Its promising